# Batch Saving Raster DTm and choosing type in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, ppygis

Follow on question from the following Previous question

[batch saving 10m DTM layers using python console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298213/batch-saving-10m-dtm-layers-using-python-console)

I would now like to set the output of my Raster .tif files to Float32 as by default the .asc files I am saving are being converted to Float64 tif files.

Does anyone know how the previous quetions code could be modified to do this? Or if there is a similar way of doing this in QGIS3 I am open to using this software also as it is now in LTR with 3.4.5

Here is the Code being used-

`myDir = 'C:\Users\david.laverty\Desktop\Save tif from asc/'
layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + "_2017"+ ".tif")
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                           width,
                           height,
                           extent,
                           layer.crs())`